# Merge two bitmask with conflict resolving, with some required distance between any two set bits

Tags: c++, x86, bit-manipulation, intrinsics

I have two integer values:
`d_a = 6` and `d_b = 3`, so-called distance between set bits.
Masks created with appropriate distance look like below:

```
uint64_t a = 0x1041041041041041; // 0001 0000 0100 0001 0000 0100 0001 0000
                                // 0100 0001 0000 0100 0001 0000 0100 0001

uint64_t b = 0x9249249249249249; // 1001 0010 0100 1001 0010 0100 1001 0010
                                 // 0100 1001 0010 0100 1001 0010 0100 1001
```

The goal is to have a `target` mask, which has bits set with `d_b`, but simultaneously takes into account bits set in the `a` mask (e.g. first set bit is shifted).

The second thing is that the distance in the `target` mask is not constant i.e. number of zeros between set bits in the `target` mask shall be equal to `d_b` or increased whenever between them is set bit in `a`

```
uint64_t target = 0x4488912224488912; // 0100 0100 1000 1000 1001 0001 0010 0010
                                      // 0010 0100 0100 1000 1000 1001 0001 0010
```

The picture to visualize the problem:
[image: target mask]

The blue bar is `a`, yellow is `b`.
I would rather use bit manipulation intrinsics than bit-by-bit operations.

**edit**:
Actually, I have the following code, but I am looking for a solution with a fewer number of instructions.

```
void set_target_mask(int32_t d_a, int32_t d_b, int32_t n_bits_to_set, uint8_t* target)
{
    constexpr int32_t n_bit_byte = std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::digits;

    int32_t null_cnt = -1;

    int32_t n_set_bit = 0;
    int32_t pos = 0;
    while(n_set_bit != n_bits_to_set)
    {
        int32_t byte_idx = pos / n_bit_byte;
        int32_t bit_idx = pos % n_bit_byte;

        if(pos % d_a == 0)
        {
            pos++;
            continue;
        }
        null_cnt++;

        if(null_cnt % d_b == 0)
        {
            target[byte_idx] |= 1 << bit_idx;
            n_set_bit++;
        }
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you combine `target` from `a` and `b`? I am not sure I could follow your explanation.

Comment: It is my goal to combine them. Let's assume that `a` means already reserved resources:

```
uint64 available = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF ^ a
```

Now I need to use `available` to create `target` according to `d_b`

Comment: But what is the combination rule? why can't you just, let's say, `OR` between them?

Comment: There aren't intrinsics for scalar `OR` or simple left or right shift because they're not needed: `|` and `<<` on `uint64_t` already express the same behaviour that an integer OR would.  Unless you mean you want to do this for multiple uint64_t elements at once, with `_mm_or_si128` or something?  Still not clear *how* you want to resolve conflicts, although you can detect them with `(x & (x<<1)) == 0` and so on for shift counts up to `d_b`.  Or perhaps something like `x - (x>>d_b)` or `(x<<d_b) - x` to get masks in each region? (untested, not sure that would fully work)

Comment: Whenever `AND` between two bits on the same position in `a` and `b` is equal to 1, then `b` shall be shifted to the left and it's clear. But the major issue is that the distance (light blue bars) between two yellow bars on the picture shall be equal to `d_b`. Please check the second and third yellow bars. Thrid needs to be shifted because the navy blue bar (with distance `d_a`, depicted `a` mask) bar is between.

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `byte_idx` and `bit_idx` are calculated at the beginning of the while loop. 
Tag switched to C++.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `int32_t byte_idx = pos / n_bit_byte;` comes into scope anew and is re-initialized every time through the while loop.  It's an odd idiom but I think that's how C/C++ works. (Not sure the logic of the whole thing makes sense, though, haven't really got to that yet; still looking at the weird `uint8_t*` which is apparently used for accessing bytes of a `uint64_t`?  So we're assuming it's `unsigned char` to be strict-aliasing safe, but not assuming that uint8_t has 8 bits despite that being 100% guaranteed :P)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I overlooked the `continue;` after the `pos++`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: (nvm, you just spotted that yourself.)  There's a `continue;` after the update, so I think it always goes back to the top of the loop after that.   Might be easier to just calculate bit/byte idx *after* that if block, and less unnecessary work for the compiler to optimize away.  That would be easier for human readers, too :P

Comment: Incidentally, how is the caller supposed to know what number to pass for `n_bits_to_set`? Too many and it will overflow `target`. Too few and it will not set every desired bit that fits in `target`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'm starting to suspect this is intended for use in a larger bit-array, not actually a single `uint64_t`.  And that it's not just supposed to fill one `uint64_t` or bitmap, but for some reason scattering a specific number of bits is interesting/useful.  (If that's not the case, you're totally right; that's a weird parameter to have.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right. `n_bits_to_set` is calculated according to the 3gpp formula. Target represents each resource element in the 5G resource grid. Resource element means single radio subcarrier. The number of resource elements depends on the channel bandwidth and can be large (for example 45864 resource elements per 1 ms slot). That's why I am looking for a faster solution

Comment: I have corrected the example result in the question body.

Comment: I think `pdep` approach suits for array processing too, since the total bit set into `uint64_t` can be determined by `popcnt`, and masks can be adjusted by left shifts,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If target is `uint64_t`, possible `d_a` and `d_b` can be converted into bit masks via look-up table. Like `lut[6] == 0x2604D5C99A01041` from your question.

Look up tables can be initialized once per program run during initlalization, or in compile time using macro or constant expressions (`constexpr`).

To make `d_b` spread, skipping `d_a` bits, you can use `pdep` with inverted `d_a`:

```c
 uint64_t tmp = _pdep_u64(d_b_bits, ~d_a_bits);
```

Then you can convert `n_bits_to_set` to contiguous bits mask:

```
 uint64_t n_bits = (1 << n_bits_to_set) - 1;
```

And spread them using `pdep` again:

```c
 uint64_t tmp = _pdep_u64(n_bits, tmp);
```

(See [Intrinsic Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=deposit&ig_expand=5208) about pdep. Note that pdep is slow on AMD before Zen3. It's fast on Intel CPUs and Zen3, but not Bulldozer-family or Zen1/Zen2)

Comment: If you knew there weren't going to be conflicts, you could apply the limit on number of bits to set with `_bzhi_u64(tmp, n_bits_to_set * d_b)` or something like that to zero that bit-position and higher.  (i.e. calculate where the bit scattering will end). But with some bits being unset due to interaction between the two LUT results, yeah another pdep probably makes sense.

Comment: It's close to the expected result, but I need to spread `d_b` with shift applied to conflicting `d_a` bits, instead of clearing them. I have tried to use BMI2 instructions with no results

Comment: @temteremte, doesn't the first `pdep` address exactly this: `tmp = _pdep_u64(d_b_bits, ~d_a_bits);` ? `tmp` should contain spread `d_b`, no?

Comment: Yes, by mistake I have switched the order of arguments. It's exactly what I needed. Thank you!